# How can I close and re-open Turtle Screen in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Could you please guide me? After I draw a square, how can I close the screen and then reopen it?

```
import turtle
win = turlte.Screen()
Man = turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(4):
    Man.fd(100)
    Man.right(90)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tkinter with `turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)`, you have access to all of Tkinter's functions, `RawTurtle` takes `canvas` as an argument, which is a tkinter canvas object. In this case, you can create a new `tkinter.Toplevel`, on which you can create a canvas, that you can use `RawTurtle` on. Something like this:

```
import turtle, random, time
from Tkinter import *
tk = Toplevel()
screen = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
screen.pack()

t = turtle.RawTurtle(screen)

t.speed(0)
t.hideturtle()

def spiral(len, angle):
    for current in range(1, int(len)):
        thetext = 'Currently turning '+str(a)+' degrees, then moving '+str(current)+' pixels'
        textitem = screen.create_text(-250, -250, text=thetext, anchor='nw', font=('Purisa', 12))
        t.forward(current)
        t.left(int(angle))
        screen.delete(textitem)
    t.up()
    t.goto(0, 0)
    t.down()


a, b = random.randint(-360, 360), 100
t.clear()
spiral(b, a)
tk.destroy()

print 'Still running'
time.sleep(1)
print 'Still running'

new = Toplevel()

newscreen = Canvas(new, width=500, height=500)
newscreen.pack()

t2 = turtle.RawTurtle(newscreen)
t2.fd(10)
```

As you can see, with `RawTurtle`, we can create and destroy tkinter windows, that contain canvases that function as turtle windows. As demonstrated in the first window, the other advantage is that you can create text and such as you would on a tkinter canvas otherwise. This code works in python 2.7, it may require some minor modification to work in python 3, I don't know. Anyway, in this example, we created and destroyed turtle windows at will. The main parts of the program are

```
tk = Toplevel()
screen = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
screen.pack()

t = turtle.RawTurtle(screen)
```

which create a new turtle window, with `t` as the turtle, and

```
tk.destroy()
```

which will kill the turtle window without stopping the program. Hope this helps!

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether you want the reopened window to have the same contents. This example will not do that, that would be more complicated.

Comment: I know it has been a long time since you posted this, but can I ask why is there another window that opens alongside the canvas and how can I stop this?

Comment: @Sank6 What do you mean by another window ?

Comment: There is another window which opens along the canvas called tk when the above is run