# Save turtle drawing

Tags: python, image, save, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am making a python program where it draws a square and I want the user to be able to save the drawing when the user presses q. All it does is add the image to the ide file directory. If it helps, I use [Replit](https://replit.com) as my ide. It does not save it directly to the users files. Here is the relevant code:

```py
import turtle
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)
def save():
 ts = turtle.getscreen()
 ts.getcanvas().postscript(file="Square.png")
turtle.onkeypress(save, key="q")
```

***Thanks in advance!***

> If it is os specific Windows, Chrome Os, and Mac.

Comment: If you want the file in a specific location, then you need to specify the location.  You can get the user's home directory from `os.environ['HOME']`.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thanks, but do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: I answered your question.  You want the image saved to the user's folder, and not the IDE's folder.  That happened because you only specified the file name, not the whole path.  You need to decide which folder you want to use, and pass that whole path instead of just the file name.

Comment: @TimRoberts I do not know the proper syntax for that. Please make an answer with the whole code example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure others will want to know how, so it's a decent question to answer properly.  This can be done, however you need to use native Tk methods, instead of trying to rely on Turtle scripts.  Pillow also helps, because you get a better render.

As I recall, background colors don't show.  To get background, you'd need to do a subprocess call to a screenshot-utility that allows commandline use on your OS ( such as scrot on Linux ).

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from PIL import Image  ##  Python Imaging Libary / Pillow
import turtle as trt
import os  ##  os.path.join( directory, filename )

##  pip3 install pillow

root  = tk .Tk()
root .title( 'Python Turtle' )
home  = os .environ['HOME']

Width, Height  = 500, 500
canvas  = tk .Canvas( root, width=Width, height=Height )
canvas .pack()

turtle  = trt .RawTurtle( canvas=canvas )
screen  = turtle .getscreen()
##  screen .bgcolor('orange')  ##  doesn't show with canvas grab

for i in range(4):
    turtle .forward(50)
    turtle .left(90)

    def screenshot():
        filename  = 'Square'
        directory  = fd .askdirectory( initialdir=home, title='Choose folder' )
        fullpath  = os .path .join( directory,  filename )
        eps, png  = f'{fullpath}.eps',  f'{fullpath}.png'
        canvas .postscript( file=eps,  pagewidth=Width -1,  pageheight=Height -1 )
        print( 'saved', eps )
        img  = Image .open( eps )  ##  use PIL to convert to PNG
        img .save( png, 'png', optimize = True, compress_level = 9 )
        os .remove( eps )
        print( f'converted to', png )

screen .onkeypress( screenshot,  key='q' )
screen .listen()
root .mainloop()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html
[How can I close and re-open Turtle Screen in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428437/how-can-i-close-and-re-open-turtle-screen-in-python)

Comment: To save background, [draw a colored rectangle as the background first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821534/pil-tkinter-canvas-eps-to-png-conversion-output-file-contains-issues).