# Python Turtle: Trying to set a custom shape for my turtles from the poly function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to make it so that the shape of the cars are customized polygons (they have to be drawn, unfortunately) but they just show up as tiny little arrows instead. I'm not sure what to do and how to make it so that they show up as the cars that I've drawn, where the cars facing right show up as the carright shape and vice versa. This is my first time using Stack Overflow, so please be patient with me. Does anybody know how to help? I'm so stuck!!

```
#import modules
import turtle, random, time

#initiate screen
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor('darkgray')
screen.delay(0)

#initiate sprite
sprite = turtle.Turtle()
sprite.shape('square')
sprite.penup()
sprite.speed(0)
sprite.ht()

#initate player (clone of sprite)
player = sprite.clone()
player.shape('turtle')
player.fillcolor('forestgreen')
player.st()

#draw car (facing left)
turtle.begin_poly()

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.pensize(1)
pen.up()
pen.setheading(90)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.down()
pen.forward(16)
pen.up()

pen.setposition(0 - 1, 0)
pen.forward(1)
pen.down()
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')   
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')    
pen.forward(5)
pen.color('red')    
pen.forward(8)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 2,0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 3, 0)

for i in range(1,4):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(2)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(13)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.setposition(0-(3+i), 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 7, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(5)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(5)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 8,0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(10)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 9, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 10, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 11, 0)

for i in range(1,3):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(14)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.setposition(0 -(11+i), 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 14, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 15, 0)

for i in range(1,3):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(14)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.setposition(0-(15+i), 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 18, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 19, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(13)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 20, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 21, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 22, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(9)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 23, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(6)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 24, 0 - 1)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 25, 0 - 2)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 26, 0 - 1)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 27, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 28, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(17)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 29, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(13)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(4)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 30, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 31, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(6)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 32, 0)

for i in range(1,6):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(2)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(17)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.setposition(0 -(32+i), 0)  

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(16)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 38, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 39, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 40, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(8)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 41, 0 + 1)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(11)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 42, 0 + 2)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(13)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 43, 0 + 3)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(11)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 - 44, 0 + 4)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(11)

pen.hideturtle()

turtle.end_poly()
carleft = turtle.get_poly()
screen.register_shape('carleft', carleft)


#draw car (facing right)
turtle.begin_poly()

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
screen = turtle.Screen()
pen.pensize(1)
pen.up()
pen.setheading(90)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.down()
pen.forward(16)
pen.up()

pen.setposition(0 + 1, 0)
pen.forward(1)
pen.down()
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')   
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')    
pen.forward(5)
pen.color('red')    
pen.forward(8)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 2,0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 3, 0)

for i in range(1,4):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(2)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(13)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.setposition(0 +(3+i), 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 7, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(5)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(5)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 8,0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(10)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 9, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 10, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 11, 0)

for i in range(1,3):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(14)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.setposition(0 + (11+i), 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 14, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 15, 0)

for i in range(1,3):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(14)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.setposition(0 +(15+i), 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 18, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 19, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(13)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 20, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 21, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 22, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(9)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 23, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(6)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 24, 0 - 1)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 25, 0 - 2)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 26, 0 - 1)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 27, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 28, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(17)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 29, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(13)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(4)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 30, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 31, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(6)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 32, 0)

for i in range(1,6):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(2)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(17)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.setposition(0 +(32+i), 0)  

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(16)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 38, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 39, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 40, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(8)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 41, 0 + 1)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(11)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 42, 0 + 2)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(13)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 43, 0 + 3)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(11)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(0 + 44, 0 + 4)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(11)

pen.hideturtle()

turtle.end_poly()
carright = turtle.get_poly()
screen.register_shape('carright', carright)

#make list of car directions
car_directions = ['carleft', 'carright']

#make list of cars
cars = []

#make cars
for i in range(7):
    car = sprite.clone()

    if i % 2:
        car.seth(0)
        car.shape(car_directions[1])
            
    else:
        car.seth(180)
        car.shape(car_directions[0])

    car.goto(random.randint(-200,200), -120+i*40)
    car.st()
    cars.append(car)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.  The first is that you're mixing *object-oriented* turtle with *functional* turtle.  That is, you're having your turtle instance `pen` do all the motions, but you're extracting the polygon from the default turtle `turtle` which hasn't gone anywhere.

Fixing this, you'll get a mask image of your car.  Here's the output of the simplification of your code below to show this:

[image]

Now we see the next issue.  You can compose a turtle cursor out of multiple colored polygons (multiple `Shape` components).  But each individual polygon is rendered in one color.  So you have to take a different approach to your car design.

Finally, you need to consider the orientation of the shape you draw to get it in sync with turtle, and make sure that it has its center of mass at `(0, 0)` so it turns cleanly with `left()` and `right()`.

```
# import modules
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

# initiate screen
screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('darkgray')

# draw car
pen = Turtle()
pen.speed('fastest')

pen.begin_poly()

pen.up()
pen.setheading(90)
pen.forward(2)
pen.down()
pen.forward(16)
pen.up()

pen.goto(1, 0)
pen.forward(1)
pen.down()
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(5)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(8)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(2, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(3, 0)

for i in range(1, 4):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(2)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(13)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(3 + i, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(7, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(5)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(5)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(8, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(10)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(9, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(10, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.goto(11, 0)

for i in range(1, 3):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(14)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(11 + i, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(14, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(15, 0)

for i in range(1, 3):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(14)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('skyblue')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(15 + i, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.up()
pen.goto(18, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(19, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(13)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(20, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(21, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(22, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(9)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(23, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(6)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.up()
pen.goto(24, -1)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.goto(25, -2)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(26, -1)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.up()
pen.goto(27, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('white')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.goto(28, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(17)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.goto(29, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(13)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(4)
pen.up()
pen.goto(30, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('skyblue')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(31, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(4)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(7)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(6)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(32, 0)

for i in range(1, 6):
    pen.down()
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.color('firebrick')
    pen.forward(2)
    pen.color('red')
    pen.forward(17)
    pen.color('black')
    pen.forward(1)
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(32 + i, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(16)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(38, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(14)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.goto(39, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(12)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(40, 0)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(8)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(41, 1)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(11)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(3)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(42, 2)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('red')
pen.forward(13)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(1)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(1)
pen.up()
pen.goto(43, 3)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.color('firebrick')
pen.forward(11)
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(2)
pen.up()
pen.goto(44, 4)

pen.down()
pen.color('black')
pen.forward(11)

pen.hideturtle()

pen.end_poly()
car_polygon = pen.get_poly()
screen.register_shape('car', car_polygon)

# make list of cars
cars = []

# initiate sprite
sprite = Turtle()
sprite.hideturtle()
sprite.shape('car')
sprite.penup()
sprite.speed('fastest')

# make cars
for i in range(7):
    car = sprite.clone()

    if i % 2:
        car.setheading(0)
    else:
        car.setheading(180)

    car.goto(randint(-200, 200), -120 + i * 40)
    car.showturtle()
    cars.append(car)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Although GIF images are an alternative, they won't turn like polygons -- turtle will always show the same image regardless of direction.  But with polygons, the turtle will turn appropriately with no additional effort.

Answer (score 1):

That's impressive for Turtle.  I was expecting Atari 2600 racecar sprites.  If they're just going left & right, then you could screenshot those images, save them as a `carleft.gif` and `carright.gif` in the same directory as your Turtle script, then [register or add the images](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.register_shape) and [use those shapes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.shape).

```
screen .register_shape( 'carleft.gif' )
screen .register_shape( 'carright.gif' )

sprite .shape( 'carleft' )
player .shape( 'carright' )
```

Comment: Ah thank you. Sadly, they have to be hand drawn due to the program I have to use. Is screenshotting the only way I can get it to work?

Comment: hmm, well you can redraw new positions every frame, if you want them to roll across screen real slow.  Hiding all your turtles can speed that up some `turtle.hideturtle()`, as well as turning on `screen.tracer( 42, 0 )` then calling `screen.update()` at the end of your draw cycle to see progress.  Could use vector arrays to draw various parts as different turtles, then have a group of a doz-turtles-per-car that all travel together.  Don't have an app for screenshots, & you can't [export the Turtle screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67910671/save-turtle-drawing/67941594#67941594)?